# Pass this.state to children in react-router 1.x / React, Flux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flux, react-router

I am performing authentication on my top level route which I have named App in using react-router. My app is using the following

```
  <div className="app-wrapper">
    <NavbarC currentUser={this.state.currentUser} />
    {this.props.children}
  </div>
```

I want to be able to pass `this.state.currentUser` to the the `this.prop.children`.

Is this possible or should I just create a new state using the UserStore I've created?

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using flux, it seems the proper way to handle it is to pull the data from the store for each route. My route looks like the following:

```
let getCurrentUserFromStore = () => {
  return { currentUser: UserStore.getCurrentUser() };
}

export default class Landing extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = getCurrentUserFromStore();
    this.onStoreChange = this.onStoreChange.bind(this);
  }
  onStoreChange() {
    this.setState(getCurrentUserFromStore());
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    UserStore.addChangeListener(this.onStoreChange);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    UserStore.removeChangeListener(this.onStoreChange);
  }
  render() {
    if ($.isEmptyObject(this.state.currentUser)) {
      return <LoginPage />
    } else {
      return <DashboardPage currentUser={this.state.currentUser} />
    }
  }
}
```